# why should we run tomcat as non-root user?

Tags: apache, security, tomcat

I know it is a good practice to not run tomcat under root user. 
But we have a already working environment with tomcat running as root (Administrator).

What are the attacks that this method is prone to ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An application running with higher privileges is not more prone to attacks than when it’s running with lower privileges.

However, if the application gets compromised, there is a difference if the attacker is able to execute arbitrary commands in behalf of the system’s user that is running the application. Then it makes a difference whether the attacker can execute commands with root privileges or with lower privileges.

To lower the impact of an application compromise, you should follow the [principle of least privilege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) and give the user running the application as least privileges as possible.